# How do I get debugging to work after building VS Code from source?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I built VS Code from source following the guide [How to Contribute](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/wiki/How-to-Contribute#build-and-run-from-source).  It seems to build fine and launches in Electron.

**Problem:**

When I try to build [vscode-samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-samples), both with the included JavaScript and TypeScript versions (I ran `npm install` on each first), I'm not able to enter debug mode with <kbd>F5</kbd>. It says *"Error: No extension installed for 'node' debugging."*

**Also...**

I tried running and debugging [an extension](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-htmltagwrap) I had previously worked on for VS Code (I'm able to do this on the distribution available on http://code.visualstudio.com.

However, I'm getting a similar error:*"No extension installed for 'extensionHost' debugging."*

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Dev build version that you are running does not include the node-debugger extension required for debugging node apps.

Lots of VSCode functionality are implemented as extensions, when the product is shipped those extensions are bundled into the released version.

if you need to run the node debugger extension within the build version, you need to add the extension to the OSS build extensions folder, to do that:

`cd ~/.vscode-oss-dev/extensions/`

`git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-node-debug && cd vscode-node-debug`

`npm install && gulp build`

This will pull the node extensions to dev build extension folder, then will build the extension. Next time you run, the dev build will load this extension, you will be able to do node debugging.

Comment: This works but for some reason when I'm debugging in the dev build, I don't get a popup when I hover over a variable.  Very annoying.